# Local VS Inherited pages in IIS

Tags: iis

Unfortunately I have deleted the 401 page at application level in IIS..
I have created a new one there back.. type of that page is local instead of inherited..
How should I get it to inherited at app level..
Tried resett but no luck

Answer (score 0):

Unless someone has changed the delegation configuration for your Error Pages, the changes made to your Application Error Pages will be made to the Application's Web.Config file.

1. Click your Application on the Left Side of IIS Manager.
2. Next Click Explore in the Top Right corner to open Windows Explorer to the Physical Path of the Application.
3. Open the Web.config in NotePad.
4. Locate the tag for < httpErrors>.

I imagine you'll only have two entries one for Remove and one for add.   If this is the case, delete everything between < ttpErrors and the closing < / httpErrors>.  (Feel free to make a backup of the web.config if you're nervous).

If you have something other than that in the web.config or you don't find it, post back with what you find.